# How do I make efficient sequential input and keystates even with the same key?

Tags: c++, input, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

I'm making a game and I wish to have a system where I can check for combinations of inputs to form a command. I have input working for singular keypresses, multiple key presses at the same time, and had at one point sequential inputs with different keys.

my system for input is a keystate of a certain length, and 4 buffers of the same length.

```cpp
int length;
const Uint8* keystate;
Uint8 *firstInput;
Uint8* secondInput;
Uint8* thirdInput;
Uint8* fourthInput;
```

then when the keyboard class inits I have them set to the same length and initialize my keystate

```cpp
keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(&length);
firstInput = new Uint8[length]; //all of them like this.
```

then during update I check for keystates and releases like this

```cpp
if(keystate[Left] && keystate[lPunch])
{
    //example
}
if(keystate[lPunch] && !keystate[Crouch] && firstInput[Crouch])
{
    //example of checking for release
}
//Outside of if statements I have the buffers mem copied, if I am doing that wrong please do tell me
//I wish for this system to be efficient
SDL_PumpEvents();
std::memcpy(firstInput, keystate, length);
std::memcpy(secondInput, keystate, length);
std::memcpy(thirdInput, keystate, length);
std::memcpy(fourthInput, keystate, length);
keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(&length);
```

The system works when not doing the same key, so how do I use this more efficiently and with repetition of keys

```cpp
//here's my attempt at using the same key, note nothing happens even with code inside
if(keystate[Left] && !secondInput[Left] && firstInput[Left]
{
    //Do dash
}
```

edit one:
adding an order of memcpy does seem to change results upon processing one in front of the other like

```cpp
memcpy(secondInput, firstInput, length);
memcpy(firstInput, keystate, length);
```

this paired with my dash code seems to make the player constantly dashing

Comment: You copy the same `keystate` into each array, so they have same contents? It makes little sense (unless modified elsewhere). Wasn't it supposed to be memcpy `third => fourth`, `second => third`, `first => second`, and finally `keystate => first`, in exactly that order?

Comment: @keltar I thought that keystate updates too fast in code to affect the memcpy speed. I did originally think to do first to second to third etc but my system uses the fourth as the newest so memcpy in that order might be the reverse solution. I'll try the suggestions and follow up with my results next edit of my post

Comment: SDL updates key state in `SDL_PumpEvents` (or indirectly via `SDL_PollEvent`). No update happens until it is called next time.

Comment: @keltar So if I were to place a pump event after the latest input and transfer them after that it would be able to work in sequence?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, and not really sure how having more than 2 arrays is useful in any way. You check that key is currently pressed and was pressed on previous frame too (so, being held for at least 1 frame? why 1 frame?), and *not* pressed two frames ago. So it will trigger only once per press but have to be held for at least 2 frames. Not really sure what logic is that. Could you explain what resulting behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @keltar Yeah I'll try to explain my thoughts. In the code questioned I want a check for a press of a key that was released a frame earlier but pressed a frame before that release, I think I realize what you're saying about not needing the buffers, but it confuses me how I would go about having the program know it was a release and not me pressing the button outright

Comment: Okay.. So as said, you need to check three buffers (two for history and one current), *but* do you really expect player to react in 1 frame precision? Is your frame rate even locked? I suppose you'll have to track time for historic data to consider if double press happens in acceptable time interval.

Comment: @keltar I actually have a timer as of now, however I can't seem to make it work with states, maybe my new conditions are wrong?